# Enforce generation of template base function

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I am using the curious recurring template pattern (CRTP) to provide functionality, which require the generation of static functions for the base class. Often, I forget to explicitly instantiate the functions and this results in wrong behavior (functions are not generated). A simple example of a singleton base class is shown below.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class Singleton {
 public:
  static const T& InstanceGet() {
    if (!pInstance) { pInstance = new T; }
    return *pInstance;
  }

  static int InstanceDestroy() __attribute__((destructor));
 protected:
  Singleton() = default;
  Singleton(Singleton const &) = delete;
  Singleton& operator=(Singleton const &) = delete;
 private:
  static T* pInstance;
};

template <class T>
int Singleton<T>::InstanceDestroy() {
  if (pInstance) {
    delete pInstance;
    pInstance = nullptr;
  }
  return 0;
}

template <class T>
T* Singleton<T>::pInstance = nullptr;

class Test : public Singleton<Test> {
  friend class Singleton<Test>;
};

// Explicit instantiate destructor (otherwise not called)
// template int Singleton<Test>::InstanceDestroy();

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const Test& pTest = Test::InstanceGet();
  return 0;
}
```

If I forget to explicitly instantiate `int Singleton<Test>::InstanceDestroy()`, the function is not generated and called when the library is unloaded. Question: Is there an automic way to ensure such functions are generated?

I found a way, but this introduces a dummy call during startup. Add the following constant to the base class

```
const int atexit = Singleton<T>::InstanceDestroy();
```

which is not very elegant.

Finally, I should mention that the question is not about how to handle singletons. I use the pattern above for making objects publishers and subscribers, garbage collected etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of the `__attribute__((destructor))` hack, I would try declaring an inner class with a garden-variety destructor, and then instantiate a static class instance of the inner class.

Comment: Do you really need to reset singleton ? Else Meyers' singleton is better.

Comment: I try to avoid Meyers singleton. We use an old compiler, which does not generate thread safe code using Meyers singleton (example is not thread safe). Also, I would like to avoid interfering with the already to many singletons registered in a huge static application

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Not really an option. I would like to avoid static variables, which automatically get inserted into an already infinite long list of function pointers. `__attribute__((destructor))` is not hack - it is the proper way to register function for calling before unloading

Comment: @SamVarshavchik A static instance of a class wouldn't that lead to the insertion of a function pointer to the destructor in the list, where the many other functions are registered using `atexit`, i.e. application exit rather than library unload